# Git not working on wsl but it is working on powershell without pat token

Tags: git, powershell, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to clone a repository using wsl but
I get the error

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository '<WORKING LINK>' not found
```

I can clone the repository using github desktop application or by using power shell

I have tried to delete the credential file as I read that it might give this problem 
After which I get the
`remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.` error. 
I do NOT have access to the PAT of the repo as I am not the owner but I am a collaborator 
The Repository is a private repository

Can anyone help with this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, add you git configurations to the system:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "youremail@domain.com"
```

Then you can create Personal Access Token from your Github account [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). Note that PAT is account specific and if you are a collaborator in a repo then you can use your PAT to do stuff (according to the privileges you have)

Now try cloning your repository normally using the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/privateRepo/privateRepo.git # using HTTPS
```

The prompt will ask for your username password/Authentication Token.

or

```
git clone https://username:token@github.com/user/repo
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply,
This worked for me, I always thought PAT was only made in a repository